# syntax error on token"[", Expression expected after this token

Tags: java, arrays, processing

randomsize is an array I want to pass to the display function in Line class, whenever i call `p.display(randomsize[])`, I expect it will pass value to `display` function. Obviously there is some other ways to make this work, just curious why does the error happen?

```
ArrayList textlines;

int xpos=20;
int ypos=20;
int[]randomsize = new int[4];

void setup() {
  size(1200, 768);
  textlines = new ArrayList();
  randomsize[0]=10;
  randomsize[1]=15;
  randomsize[2]=20;
  randomsize[3]=25;
}

void draw() {
  background(100, 100, 100);

  for (int i=0; i<textlines.size(); i++) {

    Line p=(Line)textlines.get(i);
    p.display(randomsize[]);
  }
}


void mousePressed() {
  textlines.add(new Line(xpos, ypos, thistime));
}


class Line {

  int x;
  int y;

  Line(int xpo, int ypo) {
    x =xpo;
    y =ypo;
  }

  void display(int therandom[]) {
    fill(50, 50, 50);
    rect(width/2, height/2, therandom[0], thatimee[0] );
    rect(width/2, height/3, therandom[1], thatimee[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Without giving you the answer, a helpful hint would be to find the line number of the error in question (in the event your not able to spot it on sight) and to visualize the execution of the code to see what your sending as an argument is exactly what you had intended it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong

```
p.display(randomsize[]);


void display(int therandom[]) { //here input argument should be an integer array
fill(50, 50, 50);
rect(width/2, height/2, therandom[0], thatimee[0] );
rect(width/2, height/3, therandom[1], thatimee[1]);
}
```

then you can simply call that method as follows

```
p.display(randomsize);
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass `randomsize[]` to `display()`, just `randomsize` without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
void draw() {
  background(100, 100, 100);

  for (int i=0; i<textlines.size(); i++) {

    Line p=(Line)textlines.get(i);
    p.display(randomsize); // Remove the brackets from randomsize in the scope of the method draw().
  }
}
```